# Ext.Net mvc AjaxResult in Internet Explorer not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

i got a problem with Internet Explorer 11.

I've got a button with a direct event in ext.net mvc which returns an AjaxResult:

```
X.Button()         
  .DirectEvents(de =>
  {
    de.Click.Url = Url.Action("saveNewDate");
    de.Click.FormID = "formNewDate";
  })
  .Text("Save")
```

Controller give me back an:

```
AjaxResult ar = new AjaxResult();
ar.Script = X.Msg.Alert("test", "test").ToScript();
return ar;
```

It is working in all browsers except in the Internet Explorer.
He does not display the Alert Box, instead he gives me a saveNewDate.json back for downloading.

How can i avoid this and just display the Msg Alert Box ?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

So i set 
    ar.IsUpload = true and it works fine.